# i can't get media instagram API by latitude and longitude

Tags: json, api, instagram

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

its just show me like this :

```
{
  data: [ ],
     meta: {
     code: 200
     }
}
```

is there anyways to get media by latitude & longitude ?

Comment: you need register in instagram API and give ACCESS-TOKEN use this link: https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/developer/register/

Comment: yes i already did, but still same :(  @MasoudZarjani